# Glide does not show user image when user information comes from BehaviorSubject in rx

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-glide

I have Login activity that user inserted user name and password.after login by user, all user info received by client and stored in realm database.In mainActivity these information are read and by glide image user is shown in ImageView.User image is byte array:I am using MVP design pattern:

```
private void loadProfileUserImage() {
        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.shadow);
        requestOptions.circleCropTransform();
        requestOptions.transforms(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(300));
        Glide.with(view.getContext())
                .load(userInfo.getUserImage())
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .into(view.getProfilePic());
    }
```

everything is fine and image user is shown in imageView.IN mainActivity i have a card view.when user click on my card,all user information is sent to UserInfoActivity by rx and intent.I am using `BehaviorSubject` for emitting user information:

```
view.getCard1().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        RxBus.getSubject().onNext(userInfo);
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity,UserInfoActivity.class));
    }
});
```

In `UserInfoPresenter` I want to show all user information to user.I have created Image view in UserInfo layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_user_profile"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

and in UserInfopresenter by getSubject i get user info and finally i want to show user image by glid.But nothing happen and user image is not shown by glid:`userInfo` declared as a field.

```
userInfo = new User();
compositeDisposable.add(
        MainPresenter.RxBus.getSubject()
        .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(User o) {
                userInfo = o;
                loadProfileUserImage();
            }...
```

and loadProfile method:

```
private void loadProfileUserImage() {
    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.shadow);
    requestOptions.circleCropTransform();
    requestOptions.transforms(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(300));
    Glide.with(view.getContext())
            .load(userInfo.getUserImage())
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .into(view.getProfilePic());
}
```

I did not get any error and even `placeholder drawable` is not shown in imageView!!! Like glid does not exist and it doesn't work.I put brakepoint for debugin for sure about receiving correct `User object` in this part:

```
@Override
public void onNext(User o) {
      userInfo = o;
      loadProfileUserImage();
}
```

and user is completely received and i can see user image byte array in debugging mode.

What's happen and what is you'r idea?

*****************Edit** *******************

debug mode image:

[image]

Comment: does it work if you `.load()` a static image? did you verify the dimensions/visibility of the imageview?

Comment: @TimCastelijns i put imageView in my layout in my post and i did set visibility for image view. `.load` should load byte array.I do in MainActivity and it was ok but in UserInfoActivity does not work

Comment: @TimCastelijns user image contain this info ` UserImage : [255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,72,0,72,0,0,255,254,0,87,70,105,108,101,32,115,111,117,114,99,101,58,32,104,116,116,112,58,47,47,99...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally find, where is my problem.
I am using dagger for inject dependencies and in i've injected `UserInfoView` in it's constructor:

```
@Inject
public UserInfoView(Activity activity) {
    super(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
```

Seems in this way right view is not injected to the presenter class because i have injected presenter by it's constructor:

```
@Inject
public UserInfoPresenter(UserInfoView view, Activity activity) {
    this.view = view;
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

When i put UserInfoView into my module:

```
@Provides
@UserInfoScope
public UserInfoView view() {
    return new UserInfoView(activity);
}
```

and run app, user image profile is shown and glid do right job.